# Url with %20 showing 404 error code, how to fix?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Below are my `.htaccess` rules, the first rule is for `example.com/search-words` but showing 404 error code when you reach it like this `example.com/search%20words` while the second rule `example.com/s/search-words` is working in both.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/?$ search_main.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)?$ search_main.php?q=$1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the URL you want to use? Are you trying to make a URL using a query string? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: here is the problem, (https://www.morenaija.ng/rush-ayra-starr) will load fine why this (https://www.morenaija.ng/rush%20ayra%20starr) is showing 404 error, I want to reach the page with the 2 url format. @RobinBastiaan

Comment: Those two rules match different _search phrases_ - is the intention that they should match the same?

Comment: yes, I want to reach same page with the two format

Comment: And what characters do you want to allow in the search phrase? Literally anything, including slashes? eg. `s/foo/bar/baz`?

Comment: no slashes, but all URL-encoding formats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/?$ search_main.php?q=$1
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* in the first rule does not permit *spaces*. Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+)/?$ search_main.php?q=$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the %-decoded URL-path. `%20` is a URL encoded *space*, so this regex must match a literal *space* character.

The `\s` shorthand character class denotes any white-space character.

You had an erroneous `-z` char sequence in the character class before the final hyphen. And there's no need to backslash-escape a literal hyphen when used at the start or end of the character class.

You should also include the `L` flag here.

---

**UPDATE:**

> `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9:.–\s-]+)/?$ search_maiin.php?q=$1 [L]` Dot is redirecting home page to index.php @MrWhite

The dot is now likely causing a conflict with other rules (eg. a front-controller pattern) as it will now potentially match actual files, such as `index.php`.

You could make an exception for search phrases that end in `.php`, using a negative lookahead for example: `^(?!.+\.php$)([a-zA-Z0-9:.–\s-]+)/?$`. In other words:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!.+\.php$)([a-zA-Z0-9:.–\s-]+)/?$ search_main.php?q=$1 [L]
```

OR, make sure the rule only applies to the initial request and not rewritten requests. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9:.–\s-]+)/?$ search_main.php?q=$1 [L]
```

NB: You had `search_maiin.php` (two `i`s) in your revised rule (which I assume was a typo)?

---

**UPDATE#2:**

> I'm requesting [index.php] directly.

I would not expect you to be requesting `index.php` directly. This will indeed create a conflict with the above rule, in that requests for `index.php` (or any `.php` file that is requested directly) will be routed to `search_main.php`.

Try the following instead, to specifically exclude requests for physical files (and directories):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9:.–\s-]+)/?$ search_main.php?q=$1 [L]
```

---

**UPDATE#3:**

> how do I match & sign in url? `/MP3:%20Quavo%20&%20Takeoff%20%E2%80%93%20Nothing%20Changed`

Add `&` to the (middle of the) regex character class - this char carries no special meaning in the regex. However, you'll likely need to add the `B` flag to that rule also so the `&` is URL-encoded in the query string and not seen as a URL parameter delimiter in the query string.

For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9:.–&\s-]+)/?$ search_main.php?q=$1 [B,L]
```

---

**UPDATE#4**

> can we also allow emoji?

Rather than focusing on the ever increasing character types to allow, it may be easier to just focus on the characters you don't want, eg. the slash.

To match everything except the slash (ie. URLs that consist of a single path segment) then change the `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
:
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ search_main.php?q=$1 [B,L]
```

`[^/]` is a *negated* character class that matches anything except a slash.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248656/discussion-on-answer-by-mrwhite-url-with-20-showing-404-error-code-how-to-fix).